# Where did the squared go in the 3rd line?

Tags: calculus, analysis, induction

[image]

I am unsure where the squared went after the second line, it seems it was just dropped?

Comment: Did you notice that the $\sum$ symbol disappeared as well...

Comment: It didn't disappear, it was taken to the common coefficient in the front, and parentheses were added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $a=2n+1$ and $b=n(2n-1)$ we have

$$ ab+3a^2=a(b+3a).$$

Comment: I vote + 1 for the user that can not vote your answer.

Comment: @ Sebastiano: many thanks !